# How loop into an array and switch into its index

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I have the array below:

```
let dict = [("Steve", 17),
             ("Marc", 38),
             ("Xavier", 21),
             ("Rolf", 45),
             ("Peter", 67),
             ("Nassim", 87),
             ("Raj", 266),
             ("Paul", 220),
             ("Bill", 392)]
```

How to loop through it and switch into the index in order to make operations in the three first, the three next and the last three.

Comment: Please don't put tags into the title and especially don't use special characters in titles for no reason. These make it harder in the future for people with similar problems to find your question.

Comment: Naming an array of tuples as dict it is very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.enumerated()` to get a sequence of `(idx, item)` tuples that `for` can then enumerate through.  For example:

```
let dict = [("Steve", 17),
            ("Marc", 38),
            ("Xavier", 21),
            ("Rolf", 45),
            ("Peter", 67),
            ("Nassim", 87),
            ("Raj", 266),
            ("Paul", 220),
            ("Bill", 392)]

for (idx, item) in dict.enumerated() {
    let (name, value) = item

    switch (idx / 3) {
    case 0:
        print("\(name) is in the first group")
    case 1:
        print("\(name) is in the second group")
    case 2:
        print("\(name) is in the third group")
    default:
        print("\(name) not in first 3 groups")
    }

    print("value is \(value)")
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Steve is in the first group
> value is 17
> Marc is in the first group
> value is 38
> Xavier is in the first group
> value is 21
> Rolf is in the second group
> value is 45
> Peter is in the second group
> value is 67
> Nassim is in the second group
> value is 87
> Raj is in the third group
> value is 266
> Paul is in the third group
> value is 220
> Bill is in the third group
> value is 392
> ```

or equivalently, instead of doing integer math based upon the index, you could just switch on it directly but use a range for the cases:

```
switch idx {
case 0...2:
    print("\(name) is in the first group")
case 3...5:
    print("\(name) is in the second group")
case 6...8:
    print("\(name) is in the third group")
default:
    print("\(name) not in first 3 groups")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify step of `index` by where clause:

```
for index in 0..<dict.count where index % 3 == 0 {
    // here you can do action with index, index + 1, index + 2 items in way you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split your array by chunks of given size using `Array` extension:

```
extension Array {

    func chunked(by distance: IndexDistance) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: startIndex, to: endIndex, by: distance).map {
            let newIndex = index($0, offsetBy: distance, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
            return Array(self[$0 ..< newIndex])
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
let splittedArrays = dict.chunked(by: 3)

splittedArrays.enumerated().forEach { index, subArray in
    switch index {
        case 0:
            //Do needed opertaions for the first group
            print("Players: \(subArray.map{$0.0}.joined(separator: ", "))")
        case 1, splittedArrays.endIndex - 1:
            //Do needed opertaions for the second and last group
            print("Result: \(subArray.map{$0.1}.reduce(0, +))")
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Players: Steve, Marc, Xavier
Result: 199
Result: 878
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
    
let dict = [("Steve", 17),
                ("Marc", 38),
                ("Xavier", 21),
                ("Rolf", 45),
                ("Peter", 67),
                ("Nassim", 87),
                ("Raj", 266),
                ("Paul", 220),
                ("Bill", 392)]
    for (index, (name, value)) in dict.enumerated() {
        switch index {
        case 0...2:
            // Operations for the first three elements
            print("\(name) is in the first group with value \(value)")
        case 3...5:
            // Operations for the next three elements
            print("\(name) is in the second group with value \(value)")
        case 6...8:
            // Operations for the last three elements
            print("\(name) is in the last group with value \(value)")
        default:
            // Handle any additional cases here
            break
        }
    }
```